# Ruby On Rails User Login With 2 User Types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am learning RoR for a week now and I am trying to make a login system with 2 types of users, Doctor user and Patient user. You will be able to register as a doctor only if you have the secret password (e.g 123) but you can create an ordinary patient registration using your personal details such as (mail,first name , last name etc..) . Each user will be redirected to his own page , doctor users has different Interface from the Patient users.

I do not want to use the plugins for authentication yet because i will be confused

My questions is how can i create this situation I described? Can somebody give me a simple approach on my problem?

Thanks for any insight you may have.

Comment: since you are new you should checkout railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch if you are done with that you just have to do what emptyflask said.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach to that would be to check for `params[:secret_password] == "foo"` in your controller's `create` method, then create the appropriate user.

Comment: But could you give me a more detailed version of what you are saying, i mean codewise because i am new with RoR